# .bat file: only the first line is being executed - why?

Tags: windows, batch, wget

I have the first .bat file, down.bat, for downloading movie trailers from apple.com:

```
C:\wget.exe -U "QuickTime/7.6.2" %1
```

And I also have this second file, batch.bat with all the trailers I want to download:

```
down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/ifc_films/enterthevoid/enterthevoid-tlr1_h1080p.mov
down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/fox/vampiressuck/vampiressuck-tlrc_h1080p.mov
down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/universal/skyline/skyline-tlr1_h1080p.mov
down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/sony_pictures/takers/takers-tlr2_h1080p.mov
```

When I run it from cmd.exe, only the first trailer gets downloaded, just like there is only one line in the batch.bat file.

How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In batch.bat, insert CALL before every line.

Example:

```
CALL down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/ifc_films/enterthevoid/enterthevoid-tlr1_h1080p.mov
CALL down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/fox/vampiressuck/vampiressuck-tlrc_h1080p.mov
CALL down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/universal/skyline/skyline-tlr1_h1080p.mov
CALL down http://trailers.apple.com/movies/sony_pictures/takers/takers-tlr2_h1080p.mov
```

The reason for this is that if you just start one bat file from another, only one of them will exit, while if using CALL, when the called bat file exits, the calling bat file will continue executing.